# Android Alarm Manager with broadcast receiver registered in code rather than manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I want to use an alarm to run some code at a certain time. I have successfully implemented an alarm with the broadcast receiver registered in the manifest but the way i understand it, this method uses a separate class for the broadcast receiver.

I can use this method to start another activity but I cant use it to run a method in my main activity?

([how can I notify a running activity from a broadcast receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122564/how-can-i-notify-a-running-activity-from-a-broadcast-receiver))

So I have been trying to register my broadcast receiver in my main activity as explained in the answer above.

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        uploadDB();         
    }
};    

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(null);

    this.registerReceiver(this.receiver, filter);
}

public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    this.unregisterReceiver(this.receiver);
}
```

However I have been unable to get this to work with alarm manager, I am unsure as to how i should link the alarm intent to the broadcast receiver. Could anyone point me to an example of registering an alarm manager broadcast receiver dynamically in the activity? Or explain how i would do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

How about this?

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent("WhatEverYouWant");
PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, startIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, startPIntent);
```

And then in your `Manifest.xml` file:

```
<receiver android:name="com.package.YourOnReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="WhatEverYouWant" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So as far as I know you still have to declare the receiver in the Manifest. I'm not sure if you can set it to a private instance inside of your activity. You could declare an onReceive inside of your activity and call that (if the BroadcastReceiver has an interface. I don't know if it does.)

Comment: Awesome, I managed to get it working, I didn't need to add code to the manifest though.  Just registered the broadcast receiver progamatically  with an intentfilter of the same name.

Comment: @serenskye My code is not working without registering it in manifest. How did you get away with this?

Answer (score 1):

Start a alarm intent from where you want to start alarm. write below code from where you want to start to listen the alarm

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), **AlarmReceiver**.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, shpref.getInt("timeoutint", 30));
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

And in broadcast receiver write the code you want to receive. And in menifest write below

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote"/>
```

You can also put repetitive alarm also.
Hope it help!