# Broadcast Receiver Declaration in Manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I found this code on internet and I don't know how to get permission for this Broadcast Receiver..

or I don't need to?

It's in a class SetAlarmActivity..

```
BroadcastReciever br;
private void setup() {
        br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            Toast.makeText(c, "Rise and Shine!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("org.example.makwanas.sapalarm") );
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("org.example.makwanas.sapalarm"),
            0 );
    am = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));
}
```

Comment: You already *have registered* the receiver in code using `registerReceiver`, so you do not need to *register* again in Manifest file. Permission is different.

Comment: Thanks ,, Ok one more Doubt what should be there in  registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("org.example.makwanas.sapalarm") ); at the place new IntentFilter("??");   a packege or a class?? or what exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already *have registered* the receiver in code using `registerReceiver`, so you do not need to *register* again in Manifest file. Permission is different.

Refer [documentation of registerReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29)

> filter -  Selects the Intent broadcasts to be received.

So you will need to give intent filter for which your receiver needs to receive broadcasts.

**Sample:**

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
filter.addCategory("SOME_CATEGORY");
```

You can also see this [blog](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#dynamicreceiverregistration) for more detailed explanation and examples.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank You Very Much.. But i Have added intent filter in a diffrent way..     like           registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter("org.example.makwanas.sapalarms") );         so what should be there in " " , a packege name or name of the class or what ??  like i have given now org.example.makwanas.sapalarm

Comment: okay so for alarm clock application i have added action as ALARM_SERVICE and catagory also ALARM_SERVICE ??  as you suggested me to do,, is that fine

Comment: That should be intent filter for which your receiver needs to receive broadcasts. Example: for receiving broadcast of device booted, you would need to add `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`. See [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers) and [this](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/03/android-broadcast-receiver-in-detail.html#.VE4Nhxblu1s) @Makwana

Comment: @Makwana check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7061752/1777090) for alarm + broadcast receiver.

Comment: Thanks Dude !! I understood how to deal with it.. and its working :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("Some_Broadcast");
        registerReceiver(reciever, filter);
    }

  @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (reciever != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(reciever);
            reciever = null;
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```