# Sending Messages from my Service to my Activity?

Tags: android

I have an Android Service which copies files to an ftp server.

While it is doing that, I want to send feedback to my Activity so the user knows what happens.

I tried implementing it using the [RemoteMessengerServiceSample](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample) code, but I have a problem ... All messages I send during the ftp transfer arrive at my Activity the moment the copy operation is finished ... not message by message while the copy job runs as I would like.

Is there any way to fix this? Maybe i'm using the wrong method for sending messages to my activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try issuing a Broadcast it's much more simpler than implementing the service<-->activity binding.

This will help you for the activity side [how can I notify a running activity from a broadcast receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122564/how-can-i-notify-a-running-activity-from-a-broadcast-receiver)

Comment: I'll try that, thank you. Still curious what was the problem with the MessengerService stuff though ...